# Is it possible to get a div's position when the `document.readyState` is still `interactive` (using React.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, document

I have two DIVs and the first DIV's position and height depends on the second DIV's position. Provided the second DIV will not change its position after it is rendered, I want to (and must) get the second DIV's position immediately after it is rendered, so that I can set the attributes of the first DIV and let the first DIV renders correctly, and just in time. (The actual page is huge and complicated and sorry I can only describe the relating details here. In short, this is a mobile page, it is re-rendered using some `rem auto calc` logic and every position is calculated after the related DOM is rendered.)

I've tried this (using React.js):

Add a props to the first DIV named `ready-state`, whose value is set to the `document.readyState` value.

I thought when the `document.readyState` change into `interactive` stage (the second div is rendered out), the first DIV will be re-rendered correctly.

But the truth is, I don't know which event should I listen to, so I just listened to the `readystatechange` event on document. That makes a **time gap** between the render time of the second DIV and the first DIV.

My page will block for some time after the `document.readyState` changed to `interactive`. During this time the second DIV is already rendered but the first DIV's props can not be set yet. Only when the blocking stage ended can the first DIV get the node reference to the second DIV by `document.getElementById('second-div')`.

I can get reference to `#second-div` by listening to the `readystatechange` event when the `document.readyState` is `completed`. But it is too late. (which makes the **time gap**)

The question is:

Is it possible to get a DIV's position when the `document.readyState` is still `interactive`? (Because I found the DOM node of `#second-div` is already rendered and positioned, need not wait until the `readyState` changed to `complete`.)

Comment: `I want to (and must) get the second DIV's position immediately after it is rendered` You could use componentDidMount life-cycle for that. If it is rendered using React.

Comment: @Kunukn Thank you, I'll try that.